# Temporary store a value using `java-stream`

Tags: java, java-stream

I was wondering if there is a way of temporary storing/carrying a value within a `java-stream`?

```
List<Department> departments = (ArrayList<Department>) departmentRepository.findAll();

departments.parallelStream()
        .filter(e -> e.getUnderstuffCount(date) > 0)
        .forEach(e -> {
            holidaysPlaningProblemManager.addProblem(e, date, e.getUnderstuffCount(date));
        });
```

the multiple calls for `e.getUnderstuffCount(date)` seams "dirty" and I was wondering if there is a way to avoid it by carrying the result of a single call?

**EDIT:**

Please consider this as a `java-stream` question. There are a lot of ways to solve this, for example a `@Transient` field in the `Department` `@Entity` can store the value and a simple `getter` can `return` it.

But i'm interested if this can be done using the `java-stream`

Comment: Why is it "dirty"? You call the method on different instances so you probably expect different results, no?

Comment: @assylias In this case the method is called twice on each instance, once when filtering and again when `addProblem` is called.

Comment: A popular solution is mapping `e` and `e.getUnderstuffCount(date)` to a Pair (for example AbstractMap.SimpleEntry or a two element array). You'd then have `e` and the method result available. Though I don't think that this would make it much "nicer", it can help if the method call is expensive. Another possibility is to pull the filter into the `forEach` (as an `if`), but then it's little more than a `for` loop (but parallel...).

Comment: @MalteHartwig I actually tried it. I mapped it to a `HashMap` unfortunately I wasn't able to make it work  since the `forEach` was only returning the `Integer` value and not the `Map` it self. I might have been doing it wrong though, so please feel free to elaborate with an example for this approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, there is a popular suggestion for questions like this to map a stream element to a pair containing the element itself and whichever intermediate value you need. First, let's find a simpler example (that also compiles for me):

```
Stream.of("Hello", "World", "!")
      .filter(s -> s.length() > 1)
      .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + ": " + s.length()));
// Hello: 5
// World: 5
```

If we now take either a simple array or an `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` as a pair object, we can add one mapping step:

```
Stream.of("Hello", "World", "!")
      .map(s -> new Object[] {s, s.length()})
      .filter(a -> ((int) a[1]) > 1)
      .forEach(a -> System.out.println(a[0] + ": " + a[1]));

Stream.of("Hello", "World", "!")
      .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(s, s.length()))
      .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
      .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue()));
```

The array variant is a bit shorter to write, but not type-safe. I'd use the second posibility. Or maybe you could add an actual `Pair<L, R>` class to your project with short method names and a nice factory method (`Pair.of(s, s.length())`). Whichever way you choose, it is better than collecting into a map with a collector (`stream.collect(toMap()).entrySet().stream().filter(e).forEach(e)`), as you do not materialize the whole map into memory.

---

The other possibility I mentioned is to pull the check into the forEach. Given your (possibily simplified) example, I'd say this is the most easy to read way, but is of course not as "stream-y" or "lambda-y".

```
Stream.of("Hello", "World", "!").forEach(s -> {
    int length = s.length();
    if (length > 1)
    {
        System.out.println(s + ": " + length);
    }
});
```

In this simple example, you don't even need to have a stream. Just call `Collection.forEach()`.

---

In the end you have to see whether using streams here is even worth it. You use parallel stream, but does it actually speed things up (e.g. is your `holidaysPlaningProblemManager` thread-safe or does it just synchronize all threads again, making the parallel stream pointless)? If not, you could just refactor to a normal `for` loop or `Collection.forEach`.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Its interesting, when I tried the same approach It didn't work for me. I assume I needed to create a `Map.Entry` instead of just a `Map`. Now that I look at it is obvious. Thank you for the example. Will try it out later.

Comment: Oh, yes. I thought you meant somthing like `collect(toMap()).entrySet().stream().filter().forEach()`. If you call `map` and return a real map, then it will get really difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter the departments, I think you should filter it first before retrieving it from the database and have the problem manager accept a list.

```
List<Department> departments = departmentRepository.someMethod(date);
holidaysPlaningProblemManager.addProblems(date, departments);
```

Unless you still have something to do with the elements in the collection.

Comment: I think this should be a comment rather than an answer, but it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: The `Departments` in the `List` also serve as solutions for understaffed `Departments`. Also the DB has no info if the `Department` is understaffed or not, so it's not possible to filter with a quarry.